# objective c (ios) opening sqlite database from remote server

Tags: objective-c, ios, sqlite

Looking at the sqlite3_open function, it takes a type const char for the path of the sqlite database.

I get the impression that you must download the database from a server, store it within the application and then run queries on it locally.

Is there any way to just login into the server, drop a query, save the contents of the query and drop the application? That seems like it would be way more efficient.

Anyways, if someone could just let me know the best way to tackle this, that would be awesome.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I, personally, would use a PHP Script to write/read contents and make updates to it. Taking this approach, you don't have to worry about some hackish attempt to connect to a remote database.